# How to disable trackpad taps in Yellow Dog Linux?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I just installed Yellow Dog Linux 6.2 on an old PowerPC laptop.

By default, it's interpreting trackpad taps as clicks, which I want to
disable.

I followed [the directions here](http://www.ydl.net/support/solutions/ydl_2.x/mouse_buttons.shtml), and put `TRACKPAD_OPT=notap` in my `/etc/sysconfig/mouse-emulation` and rebooted, but taps are still interpreted as clicks.  Putting the setting in `/etc/sysconfig/mouse` instead (which I had to create) and rebooting didn't fix the problem either.

I also tried:

```
% sudo trackpad notap
Password:
writing /dev/adb: No such device or address
```

So that didn't seem to work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly it's been awhile since I've used YDL but as I remember it, it should go in /etc/sysconfig/mouse not /etc/sysconfig/mouse-emulation. Perhaps that is worth a try.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: Not that I can see during boot.  Any logs I should check?

Comment: I would look at where syslog routes your kernel facility, your info level logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it goes in Yellow Dog Linux, so my answer might not help you. Anyway ...

I have an old PowerPC Mac too (iBook G4) running Ubuntu, and disabled the trackpad click using:

```
sudo trackpad notap
```

I guess you need the program trackpad to be installed. It comes with the mouseemu package in Ubuntu. If the software is the same in Yellow Dog, you should have that command too.

Now, a quick googling for "yellow dog trackpad notap" [turned up this](http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showpost.php?s=e8973a72a75e94f11946e01caad21bbc&p=323663&postcount=2).

Try it. I believe that it just executes `trackpad notap` on boot, but it's just a guess.

Comment: No dice.  I tried it and got `writing /dev/adb: No such device or address`.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "yellow DOg" linux but this is what I use in my Linux to turn off my pad on my lap top. its just a copy and paste of what I do to turn that dang thing off

```
# Turn off touch pad
# placed in ~/.xproflie also 
exec xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
exec synclient touchpadoff=1 
exec synclient VertEdgeScroll=0 
exec synclient TapButton1=0
exec synclient TapButton2=0
exec synclient TapButton3=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `synclient TouchpadOff=1` to disable and `synclient TouchpadOff=0` 
to enable from the terminal. This will affect current session only. Run with `sudo` if permission is denied.

Comment: Does this disable the trackpad *entirely*, or just the "taps as clicks", which is the question at-hand?

Comment: Indeed, following from https://askubuntu.com/questions/553791/official-documentation-of-synclient-parameters to https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html it seems that this turns the touchpad off.

Answer (score 0):

Run `xinput` to get list of your input devices. You need to find your trackpad id. I don't have trackpad so I show an example with a touchpad:

```
$ xinput
└> xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09E1:00 04F3:30CB Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09E1:00 04F3:30CB Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

As you can see, my touchpad id is 12. Next, run `xinput list-props 12`. It will give you list of device options.

```
libinput Tapping Enabled (369): 1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (371):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (373):       0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (349):       1
```

Now, to disable tapping, just run `xinput set-prop 12 369 0`
But since device id and can change, it's better to use names:

`xinput set-prop "DELL09E1:00 04F3:30CB Touchpad"  "libinput Tapping Enabled" 0`
put the line above in your `~/.xprofile` file and re-login.